# Why UITableViewCell's cellForRowAt method not calling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have already setup delegate and datasource of tableView in storyboard and I had array fill with certain data for tableView.

When I reload tableView, it will call numberOfRowsAt method but it can't for cellForRowAt.

It works fine when I refresh whole page by swiping from other page. But in certain cases it doesn't work.

Is there any other missing code other than array count and delegate-datasource connection in order to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: can you please show some code here.

Comment: It looks like the numberOfRowsForSection returning 0 count.

Comment: No. This methods return perfect counts from array. I have debug this before reloadData method and in this method also by printing array count.

Comment: I think that you have to reload table after value array fill up with data.Please send some code so we can give you suggestion.

Comment: One more reason to cellForRowAtIndex not being called is visibility of UITableView. Make sure your tableView is visible (not hidden) and also check height of tableView (It should not be 0)

Comment: I'm reloading tableView after inserting data in array. The visibility is not hidden and height of cell is set to 52.0 constants value for all cell.

Comment: @Vivek Height of tableView? Also you should add some code snippet in your question.

Comment: If you are getting number of rows then try to reload on main queue.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that your delegates as properly set to containing viewController, I would recommend implementing tableView delegates and datasource programmatically:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
```

Also, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called when `numOfRowsAtIndexPath` returns 0.

Comment: Yes. you're right. But I have taken notice as you explains and even checking minor and silly mistakes for this issue also. However, I can't able to find and solve this.

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet for tableView delegate and datasource methods from your code. Also, let me know how you are modifying the array used for populating the tableview.